# What is necessary to store in session to redirect the user to the registration page after login?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to have a context like this image:

[image]

A unauthenticated user can access the congress details page `single.blade.php` and he can select the quantities that he want for each ticket type. After click `Next`, if is not authenticated he goes to the "login.blade.php" to login. After login he should be redirected to the `registration.blade.php`.

So for the first screen I have this from action and route:

```
<form method="post" 
action="{{route('congresses.registration', 
['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">


Route::get('/congress/{id}/{slug?}', [
    'uses' => 'FrontController@show',
    'as'   =>'congresses.show'
]);
```

For the user access the registration page he should be authenticated, so there is this route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
        Route::post('/congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration', [
        'uses' => 'RegistrationController@storeQuantity',
        'as'   =>'congresses.registration'
    ]);
  }
```

**Doubt:** Do you know which data and what is necessary to store in session so is possible to redirect the user to the registration page after login?

With the code I have for now without using sessions, the user select the quantities and click in "Next", then the user introduce the email and password click in "Confirm" and then the user is redirected to "http://layout.test/congress/1/congress-title-test/registration" but it appears always "`Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`".

**LoginController:**

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectTo);

    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Middleware group                                URI                                       NAME                            ACTION
    Get | Head | Web                            /                                          /                      App\Http\Controllers\FrontController@index

    Get | Head | Web                     congress/{id}/{slug?}                   congresses.show               App\Http\Controllers\FrontController@show

    Get | Head | POST | PUT 
    | PATCH | DELETE | 
    OPTIONS | WEB | AUTH             congress/{id}/{slug?}/registration     congresses.registration App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController@storeQuantity
```

I also have the default laravel auth routes.

Comment: I understand that you want to use `POST` when submitting your form, and in this case you really need to store the information in your session. But have you considered using a form with a `GET` action? The parameters of your first form should then be part of the `route()->intended()` that can be called as part of the login routine. As you are not storing any information yet after submitting the first form, I also don't see a code smell within not using `POST`.

Comment: Thanks, can you give a example about how to do that correctly? I change the form to "                                <form method="get" action="{{route('congresses.registration')}}">".
" But Im not understanding how to get the parameters in the LoginController.

Comment: But in the first screen the selected quantites by the user are stored in an array using the RegistrationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. screen 1 should submit to a route protected by auth middleware.

B. the route protected by auth middleware should return screen 3

A-a. The auth middleware will take care of screen 2 and move them on to screen 3 when they are registered/logged in.

Comment: Thanks but like that it seems that is like its in the question and it appears the error "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException".

Comment: Gothcha.  Try making it Route::any(...) even just temporarily to see if you can push past it.

Comment: Or Route::match(['post','get'], ...) would be tighter.

Comment: Sorry but I didnt understand, can you explain better?

Comment: Your routes are tightly restricted (good) - as Route::get(...) and Route::post(...).  If you change those to Route::any(...) you'll blow past that symphony MehodNotAllowedException - because you'll be allowing any method.

Comment: Thanks, like that instead the user is redirected to  "http://layout.test/congress/1/congress-title-test/registration" is redirected to "http://layout.test/home" and it appears "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.".

Comment: Ok, let's call that progress...  run php artisan route::list and add the relevant section of the output to your question.

Comment: FYI: '/home' is where laravel tries to send users when it doesnt' know what else to do with them.  its a little annoying and is hard-coded in a few places.

Comment: Thanks, I update with some routes, not all, but for the context maybe are the necessary rotues.

Comment: From that route:list output - we need to also see the middleware column to ensure you have web, auth, and see  what else is going on with the route.

Comment: Just stumbled onto something and thought of this thread.  If you look at Illuminate\Foundation\Auth; RedirectsUsers (a trait) - you'll see a method called redirectPath() that is producing the /home.  Your can override that method in App\Http\Controllers\Auth; LoginController.php